# R glmnet error binary logistic

Tags: r

I am looking for some help figuring out what is causing an error in my attempt to fit a regularized logistic regression (specifically finding the optimal lambda value using cv.glmnet).

Running the following command:

```
RegLR_CV<-cv.glmnet(x=train.sub.clean[,-c(431)],
                    y=as.factor(train.sub$finalAttrite),
                    family="binomial")
```

where the table `train.sub.clean` are all numeric and has had all zero variance variables removed (using the `caret` package).

This function runs for a while then produces the following error. Can anyone recommend what I should be looking for to troubleshoot? It must be my data set as the toy examples in the package run fine.

> Error:
>
> Error in as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta) :   error in evaluating
>   the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error
>   in t(.Call(Csparse_dense_crossprod, y, t(x))) :   error in evaluating
>   the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error:
>   invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix

R: 
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

glmnet: 1.7

Comment: You ought to upgrade to the current version R and if that doesn't work, post results of sessionInfo() and some data that recreates the problem.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly convert `train.sub.clean[,-c(431)]` to a matrix yourself? Can you confirm that there are no `NA`s in there? Also, you're doing crossvalidation for logistic regression. Could it be that you have extremely few of either outcome class? This would make it plausible that one of the subsets doesn't contain one of the values.

Answer (score 1):

I had these same errors when I started experimenting with glmnet.  They went away when I:

1) Used model.matrix to convert all my factor variables to dummies

2) Made sure everything was coded as numeric - the presence of character variables caused the 'Error: invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix' for me.

3) Converted my data frame into two matrices for predictors and outcomes, before feeding them to glmnet.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Try to do:
cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(train.sub.clean[,-c(431)]),...)
and have a try

Comment: But is this the answer.  Tries need to be in comments